# JavaFX TextField setStyle of -fx-text-fill sometimes ignored

Tags: eclipse, javafx, textfield

The Scene contains a VBox, which contains an HBox, which has 3 children.  Each of the 3 children is a subclassed StackPane containing a TextField. the HBox has setStyle("-fx-background-color:magenta;");, each of the 3 TextFields has setStyle("-fx-text-fill:yellow;-fx-background-color:pink;");. The 1st subclassed StackPane has setStyle(""); the 2nd has setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;"); and the 3rd has setStyle("-fx-font-size:20;");

```
public class Test extends Application {  
  static public void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }
  public Test(){ } 
  public class S1 extends StackPane {
    public S1(String style, String text) {
      TextField textField = new TextField(text);
      textField.setEditable(false);
      textField.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:yellow;-fx-background-color:pink;");
      getChildren().setAll(textField);
      setStyle(style);
    }
  }
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    VBox vb = new VBox();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(vb, 600, 100));
    stage.show();
    vb.requestFocus();
    HBox hb1 = new HBox(new S1("", "AA "), new S1("-fx-background-color:green;", "BB"), new S1("-fx-font-size:20;", "CC"));
    hb1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:magenta;");
    vb.getChildren().add(hb1);
  }
  @Override
  public void stop() { }
}
```

Expected Results: all 3 TextFields to have yellow text

Actual Results: 1st TextField has yellow text, the 2nd and 3rd have black text

I am a long retired assembler programmer, teaching myself Java and Object Oriented programming for 'fun', and I really can't figure out why the above code doesn't work... is it something I am missing or have I found a bug ?

Actual results image

[image]

Windows 11, Java jdk-17.0.4.1, javafx-sdk-20.0.2 (currently latest version), Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using your code (Windows 10, Java/JavaFX 20.0.1). All three text fields always have yellow text.

Comment: windows 11, java jdk-17.0.4.1, javafx-sdk-20.0.2 (currently latest version), Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0).  I'll try exporting from Eclipse.  The exported program works.  Hopefully getting latest version of Java and/or Eclipse will solve it not working in the IDE, otherwise it's gonna be a pain having to export for each test.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Upgraded Eclipse to 2023-06, no change.  Then upgraded Java to 20.0.2, program now displays correctly both within Eclipse and after being exported.... thanks again @Slaw

Comment: @Slaw.  I have edited my original post to add my software levels, if you could change your comment into an answer (suggesting I install current versions of eclipse & java) I will be able to 'accept' your answer

Comment: It may make more sense for you to answer the question yourself, since all I contributed was saying I couldn't reproduce the problem in a relatively newer version of Java. It was you who figured out that upgrading solved the problem. Though I'm curious if the version of Eclipse had any effect, which would surprise me, or if the problem was fixed solely by upgrading Java. That all said, if you'd prefer I write an answer, I can.

Comment: @Slaw a [self-answer requires 15 points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).  If you upvote the question, GreySloth will be able to post a self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I read the comment from @Slaw (which showed his software) I realized I had only tried running via Eclipse launch, so I exported code and ran without Eclipse. When the exported code worked, I decided to upgrade Eclipse.

Upgrading Eclipse from 2021-12 to 2023-06 by itself did not solve it, but additionally upgrading Java from 17.0.4.1 to 20.0.2 did.

Conclusion: Upgrading Java was required to fix it, and upgrading Eclipse may or may not have been required.